# qt c++ new similar method. Do I overload method, write new method, or use default parameter?

Tags: c++, qt, methods, overloading, default-parameters

I have a question:

I have a huge C++ program that I have to adjust to new needs. In the program I have an existing method which is used about 20 times in my code

```
void doSomething();
```

Now I need to use a very similar new method in my program ( to use once or twice). This new method needs to doSomethingSimilar when a flag is set. I have several Ideas how to code that. Is there a best solution/style to do that?

**Idea 1:**
write another method which is almost the same as doSomething(). But this means duplicating code.

```
void doSomethingElse();
```

**Idea 2:**
overload my method ( but still duplicate code)

```
void doSomething(bool myFlag);
```

**Idea 3:**
use default parameters and include an if-statement in the old method doSomething().

```
void doSomething(bool myFlag=false);
```

Is there a best solution for that? Or an even better solution?

Thank you

Merchaldes

Comment: This is a general OO/Architecture/C++ Style kind of question, and the best answer is a bit context/environment dependent, of which there is really none provided in this question.  Suggest getting some C++ books that go into the ins and outs of C++ programming, like those by Scott Meyers, or search the net for those kind of discussions.

Comment: Code duplication isn't necessarily bad - it depends on the code's intent. That is, if X and Y are the same and should always and forever be the same, regardless of the contents of X and Y, then that's probably a bad duplication. If the code is coincidentally duplicated - X and Y just happen to be the same *right now* - then code duplication may well be the best solution. Prematurely "unduplicated" ("DRIED"?) code can be a mess to untangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate common part(s) of old method into private/protected helper method(s). Then write your two public methods so they call the helper method(s).

So basically your option 1, except don't duplicate code. Or possibly option 2, if it makes sense to overload instead of introducing new method name (in which case, see below).

Using differently named methods is explicit about what each call does, because method name says it directly without needing to check what missing/true/false arg actually means. But if you want to do it with optional arg and single method anyway (in public and protected interfaces, at least), better to declare an enum, which has descriptive value names (also, if you need third value, it's easy to add, unlike with boolean). This is what Qt generally does [(example)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CaseSensitivity-enum).

Answer (score 0):

You can outsource different parts to private helper functions. Then overload your function with the needed parameters.